# approximating function to derivative converge uniformly

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, uniform-convergence

I remember reading somewhere that for a $f\in C_c^1(\mathbb{R})$, by definining

$$f_n(x) := \frac{f(x+1/n)-f(x)}{1/n},$$

we have that $f_n(x) \longrightarrow f'(x)$ uniformly.

I'm pretty sure the compact support condition needs to hold for this, but when I tried proving this claim, I can't see where I assumed this, or where the proof fails:

For a given $\epsilon > 0$, choose $N$ so that $|x-y| < 1/N$ implies $|f'(x)-f'(y)| <  \epsilon$. Then for any $x_0\in \mathbb{R}, n>N$, from the MVT we have a $\gamma_{x_0,n} \in (x_0, x_0 + 1/n)$ such that $|f_n(x_0)-f'(x_0)| = |f'(\gamma) - f'(x_0)|$. But since $|\gamma - x_0| < 1/n < 1/N$, it follows that $|f_n(x_0)-f'(x_0)| < \epsilon$.

So which step in the proof is incorrect/uses compact support-ness?

Comment: The very first, you use the uniform continuity of $f'$. Of course compact support is not necessary for that, but $C^1$ doesn't suffice for that.

Comment: @DanielFischer Oops, I meant using compact supportness.

Comment: $g$ is continuous on $[a;b]$ implies $g$ is uniformely continuous on $[a;b]$. but $g$ is continuous on $[a;\infty[$ doesn't imply that anymore, nor continuous on $]a;b[$ (think to $g(x) = 1/x$ continuous on $]0;1]$)

Comment: I think you misunderstood my comment. You use the compact support to have the uniform continuity of $f'$ right at the start. While there are $C^1$ functions without compact support for which the derivative is uniformly continuous - $\sin$ for example - the uniform continuity of $f'$ needs additional hypotheses beyond $f\in C^1$. Compact support is a sufficient condition.

Comment: @DanielFischer Right, since $f$ has compact support, it's uniformly cts when restricted to this, and hence uniformly cts on the whole of $\mathbb{R}$. Thanks!

Comment: For future internet people who have the same hiccup: remember that a cts functions and a uniformly cts function are different... D'oh!